# The network adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: java, oracle

Below is my connection string while connecting to database:

```
public static void createConnection() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

            try {

                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;

            }

            System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

            Connection connection = null;

            try {

                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:brdqa", "STATICDATA_APP",
                        "password");

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;

            }
```

When running this code, I get the exception below:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.markit.scripts.ConnectMRD.createConnection(ConnectMRD.java:32)
    at com.markit.scripts.ConnectMRD.main(ConnectMRD.java:54)
```

I google a lot and found that problem exist with this connection string only.
In String "brdqa" is my database name and "STATICDATA_APP" is my user name. I am able to access database manually.
Please suggest.

Comment: Do you have a running oracle server on localhost port 1521?

Comment: 1521 is mentioned in my TNS entry.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Is it running? Is anybody listening at port 1521?

Comment: I am new to windows .can you please let me know the way to check this

Comment: 1- Open "cmd.exe" -> run "netstat -n -b" -> check the output for "tnslsnr.exe" OR "cmd.exe" -> "telnet localhost 1521" -> if it opens telnet then Oracle Listener is running otherwise it will say cannot connect or something.

Comment: show a sctreenshot of how you are connecting manually -  if using sql developer show the connection properties. Your conneciton string is wrong or something is blocking access

Comment: If you don't know whether it's running why are you trying to connect to it?

Comment: Use the SERVICE_NAME instead of SID. jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/brdqa (note! forward slash means SERVICE_NAME).

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the driver wasn't able to connect the socket to host "localhost" on port 1521.

You can double-check that the same connection string works with sqlplus:

```
sqlplus "STATICDATA_APP/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=brdqa)))"
```

It's common for the listener to not support "localhost" as the hostname. Have you tried with the local IP address "127.0.0.1"?

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:brdqa"
```